# What is the difference between memory barrier and complier-only fence

Tags: c++, gcc, processor, memory-barriers

As the question stated, I'm confused about the difference between memory barrier and complier-only fence.

Are they the same? If not what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a concrete example, consider the following code:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;

void foo() {
    x = 10;
    y = 20;
}
```

As it stands, without any barriers or fences, the compiler may reorder the two stores and emit assembly (pseudo)code like

```
STORE [y], 20
STORE [x], 10
```

If you insert a compiler-only fence between `x = 10;` and `y = 20;`, the compiler is inhibited from doing this, and must instead emit

```
STORE [x], 10
STORE [y], 20
```

However, suppose we have another observer looking at the values of `x` and `y` in memory, such as a memory-mapped hardware device, or another thread that is going to do

```
void observe() {
    std::cout << x << ", ";
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

(Assume for simplicity that the loads from `x` and `y` in `observe()` do not get reordered in any way, and that loads and stores to `int` happen to be atomic on this system.)  Depending on when its loads take place with respect to the stores in `foo()`, we can see that it could print out `0, 0` or `10, 0` or `10, 20`.  It might appear that `0, 20` would be impossible, but that is actually not so in general.

Even though the instructions in `foo` stored `x` and `y` in that order, on some architectures without strict [store ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering), that does not guarantee that those stores will become *visible* to `observe()` in the same order.  It could be that due to [out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution), the core executing `foo()` actually executed the store to `y` before the store to `x`. (Say, if the cache line containing `y` was already in L1 cache, but the cache line for `x` was not; the CPU might as well go ahead and do the store to `y` rather than stalling for possibly hundreds of cycles while the cache line for `x` is loaded.)  Or, the stores could be held in a [store buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_buffer) and possibly flushed out to L1 cache in the opposite order.  Either way, it is possible that `observe()` prints out `0, 20`.

To ensure the desired ordering, the CPU has to be told to do so, often by executing an explicit *memory barrier* instruction between the two stores.  This will cause the CPU to wait until the store to `x` has been made visible (by loading the cache line, draining the store buffer, etc) before making the store to `y` visible.  So if you ask the compiler to put in a memory barrier, it will emit assembly like

```
STORE [x], 10
BARRIER
STORE [y], 20
```

In this case, you can be assured that `observe()` will print either `0, 0` or `10, 0` or `10, 20`, but never `0, 20`.

(Please note that many simplifying assumptions have been made here.  If trying to write this in actual C++, you'd need to use `std::atomic` types and some similar barrier in `observe()` to ensure its loads were not reordered.)

Comment: All you explained are `memory barrier`. What about `compiler-only fence`?

Comment: @Hovin: That's the third sentence.  The compiler-only fence just tells the compiler not to reorder the store instructions.

Comment: @Hovin: It might be useful by itself if you knew that for your particular situation, the CPU wouldn't do any reordering.  For instance, maybe your variables `x,y` are in the memory space of some memory-mapped hardware device, and you happen to know that your CPU is set up to never reorder stores to device memory.  Then the barrier instruction would be unnecessary, and a compiler-only fence would suffice.

Comment: @Hovin: The other point is that any mechanism in a high-level language that should insert a memory barrier must *also* imply a compiler fence at the same point.  A memory barrier without a compiler fence is useless - it does you no good to have a barrier if you don't know which instructions are on which side of it.

Comment: concrete examples: `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` usually has to be a full memory barrier, but `atomic_signal_fence` only has to be a compiler barrier.  Or `asm("" :::"memory")` is a compiler barrier, `asm("mfence" ::: "memory)` is also a runtime full barrier.  (Where it gets tricky is that `asm("" ::: "memory")` is a valid implementation of `atomic_thread_fence(acq_rel)` on x86 because the HW already guarantees enough ordering that blocking compile-time reordering is all you need to do.  But you can still call it a proper memory barrier that just happens to be cheap on x86 :P)

Answer (score 4):

A memory barrier is implemented in hardware, and stops the CPU itself from reordering the instructions.

However, a compiler-only fence stops the compiler's optimizer from reordering instructions, but the CPU can still reorder them.

Comment: If so, will either of them constrain instructions' execution order? I'm still confused. What are they work for respectively? How to decide which one I should use?

Comment: @Hovin A memory barrier will stop the CPU from reordering the base assembly operations, while with a compiler fence the CPU can reorder as it sees fit.

Comment: BTW, any useful high-level wrapper for a barrier instruction will also *include* a compiler barrier, so you know which compile-time ordering you're nailing down to force at runtime.

Comment: @PeterCordes This makes sense.